# How do I initialize a multi-node Cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I installed Cassandra DB on my Ubuntu VM1 and also installed on other VM Ubuntu VM2.
MY question is:

How to initialize multi node cluster (single data-center) on my VM's?

I also changed my Cassandra.yaml like below:

1. IP default to IP system seed , listen_address.
2. cluster_name: 'MyDigitalOceanCluster'
3. initial_token: 0
4. seed_provider:
5. seeds:  "198.211.50.0"
6. listen_address: 198.211.50.0
7. rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
8. endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

After the changes I received this message:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': 
error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: 
Connection refused")})
```

Comment: How are you seeing that error?  From cqlsh?

Comment: Just wondering, because an IP address should really be specified with `cqlsh`.  Also, the `seeds:` parameter should have both IP addresses (in a 2 node cluster, I'd make them both seed nodes).

Answer (score 2):

Aaron has pretty much given you the answers but for what it's worth set the following in `cassandra.yaml`:

- `num_tokens: 16` or if you prefer to specify tokens, make sure you pick tokens which are balanced
- `listen_address: private_ip`
- `rpc_address: public_ip` (or same IP if your VM only has 1 NIC)
- set `seeds` to the IP of both nodes (1 of the nodes is sufficient but 2 is preferred)
- `endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` is recommended and almost always the right choice (see my reasons here https://community.datastax.com/questions/8887/)

When connecting with `cqlsh`, you need to specify the node's client IP (`rpc_address`) otherwise it will default to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`). For example:

```
$ cqlsh 198.211.50.0
```

Cheers!

Comment: thank you so much, but i dont understand. i mean i changed cassandra yaml like this: 1- listen_address: private_ip     2- seed: other node private_ip   3- rpc_address: private_ip  and I'm working on my local VM and i dont have any public address? what do you mean when you are talking about public address because i dont have any public_ip ???? what can i do now?????

Comment: As I stated in my answer, you can use the same IP for both `listen_address` and `rpc_address` if your VM only has 1 NIC. Cheers!